# Regex to target adjacent lowercase and uppercase Char

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function spinalCase(str) {

  //Replace aB to a-B
  return str.replace(/[a-z]+[A-Z]/,'$1,-,$2');
}

spinalCase('ThisIsSpinalTap');
```

I want this input "ThisIsSpinalTap" to output "This-Is-Spinal-Tap" by using a regex to target lowercase letters adjacent to uppercase, and adding a `-` inbetween. Incorrect output I am getting is this.

> t$1,$2sspinaltap

MDN reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [capturing groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) -

```js
function tap(str) {
  return str.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2');
}

console.log(tap('ThisIsSpinalTap'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need brackets around the parts you expect to be $1 and $2.

```
/([a-z]+)([A-Z])/
```